# JavaScript Quiz Ending Before All Questions Asked

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning JavaScript right now and I'm creating a quiz. My quiz runs properly without any errors in the console, but it's skipping questions and sometimes ends the quiz before all questions have been answered. It will also diminish time even if a correct answer is given.

I'm not really sure why its doing what its doing because in my mind its coded correctly. Given that I'm here asking for help means that its clearly not correct. If someone could help me adjust the code so that it functions properly, I would really appreciate it!

```js
var quizButton = document.querySelector("#quiz-button")
var timer = 75
var quizTimer = document.querySelector("#quiz-timer")
var questionIndex = 0
var score = 0
var questionBoxElement = document.querySelector('#question-box')

var questions = [
  // add questions here!!
  // question 1
  {
    questionText: "This is question 1",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. correct", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "b. correct"
  },
  // question 2 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 2",
    options: ["a. correct", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "a. correct"
  },
  // question 3
  {
    questionText: "This is question 3",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. correct"],
    answer: "d. correct"
  },
  // question 4 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 4",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  },
  // question 5
  {
    questionText: "this is question 5",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  }
];

var answerBtn0 = document.querySelector("#option0");
var answerBtn1 = document.querySelector("#option1");
var answerBtn2 = document.querySelector("#option2");
var answerBtn3 = document.querySelector("#option3");

var answers = [answerBtn0, answerBtn1, answerBtn2, answerBtn3]

// display questions
function displayQuestion() {
  let question = questions[questionIndex];
  let answerOptions = question.options;

  let questionEl = document.querySelector("#question");
  questionEl.textContent = question.questionText;



  for (var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
    let answerChoices = answerOptions[i];

    let answerBtn = answers[i];

    answerBtn.textContent = answerChoices;

  }




  document.querySelector("#answer-buttons").addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);


  // check for correct answer

  function correctAnswer(answerBtn) {
    return answerBtn.textContent === question.answer;
  }

  // checkif answeris correct
  function checkAnswer(event) {
    let answerBtn = event.target;
    // correct answer 
    if (correctAnswer(answerBtn)) {
      score = score + 20;
    }
    // incorrect answer 
    else {
      if (timer > 10) {
        timer = timer - 10;
      } else {
        timer = 0;
        endQuiz();
      }
    }

    questionIndex++;

    // if no more questions, end quiz
    if (questionIndex < questions.length) {
      displayQuestion();
    } else {
      endQuiz();
    }
  }


  function endQuiz() {
    let finalScore = document.querySelector("#scores")
    finalScore.textContent = "You scored " + score + "! Great Job!";
  }










}
// timer countdown
function countdown() {
  var timeLeft = setInterval(() => {

    if (timer >= 0 || questionIndex < 5) {
      quizTimer.textContent = timer + " seconds left";
      timer--;
      //questionIndex ++;

    } else {
      clearInterval(timeLeft);

      // call game over function
    }
  }, 1000);
}


//Start function
function startQuiz() {
  var startQuizIntro = document.querySelector(".start-quiz-intro")
  startQuizIntro.setAttribute("class", "hide")

  questionBoxElement.classList.remove("hide")

  console.log(questionBoxElement);
  // reset timer and score
  userScore = 0;

  countdown();
  displayQuestion();
}

// One Line to call one function
quizButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
```

```html
<div id="quiz-timer"></div>

<header class="start-quiz-intro">
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Coding Quiz</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="center-button">
    <p class="start"> Press Button To Start The Quiz</p>
    <button id="quiz-button">Start</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="hero">
  <div id="question-box" class="hide">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button id="option0" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option1" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option2" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option3" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <h3 id="scores"></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  Thanks for playing my game - Reid
</footer>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. See the console errors

Comment: JS is case sensitive. You have uppercase `I` here: `let answerChoices = nswerOptions[I];
   let answerBtn = answers[I];`

Comment: thats really weird. those arent uppercase in my source code. just on this snippet here

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

1. `I` is case sensitive
2. You add the eventListener more than once - fixed by moving the functions OUTSIDE the displayQuestion

```js
var quizButton = document.querySelector("#quiz-button")
var timer = 75
var quizTimer = document.querySelector("#quiz-timer")
var questionIndex = 0
var score = 0
var questionBoxElement = document.querySelector('#question-box')

// check for correct answer

function correctAnswer(answerBtn, question) {
  return answerBtn.textContent === question.answer;
}

// checkif answeris correct
function checkAnswer(event) {
  let answerBtn = event.target;
  // correct answer 
  let question = questions[questionIndex];
  if (correctAnswer(answerBtn, question)) {
    score = score + 20;
  }
  // incorrect answer 
  else {
    if (timer > 10) {
      timer = timer - 10;
    } else {
      timer = 0;
      endQuiz();
    }
  }
  questionIndex++;
  // if no more questions, end quiz
  if (questionIndex < questions.length) {
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    endQuiz();
  }
}

function endQuiz() {
  let finalScore = document.querySelector("#scores")
  finalScore.textContent = "You scored " + score + "! Great Job!";
}
var questions = [
  // add questions here!!
  // question 1
  {
    questionText: "This is question 1",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. correct", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "b. correct"
  },
  // question 2 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 2",
    options: ["a. correct", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "a. correct"
  },
  // question 3
  {
    questionText: "This is question 3",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. correct"],
    answer: "d. correct"
  },
  // question 4 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 4",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  },
  // question 5
  {
    questionText: "this is question 5",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  }
];

var answerBtn0 = document.querySelector("#option0");
var answerBtn1 = document.querySelector("#option1");
var answerBtn2 = document.querySelector("#option2");
var answerBtn3 = document.querySelector("#option3");

var answers = [answerBtn0, answerBtn1, answerBtn2, answerBtn3]

// display questions
function displayQuestion() {
  console.log(questionIndex)
  let question = questions[questionIndex];
  let answerOptions = question.options;

  let questionEl = document.querySelector("#question");
  questionEl.textContent = question.questionText;
  for (var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
    let answerChoices = answerOptions[i];
    let answerBtn = answers[i];
    answerBtn.textContent = answerChoices;
  }
}
// timer countdown
function countdown() {
  var timeLeft = setInterval(() => {

    if (timer >= 0 || questionIndex < 5) {
      quizTimer.textContent = timer + " seconds left";
      timer--;
      //questionIndex ++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(timeLeft);
      // call game over function
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//Start function
function startQuiz() {
  var startQuizIntro = document.querySelector(".start-quiz-intro")
  startQuizIntro.setAttribute("class", "hide")

  questionBoxElement.classList.remove("hide")

  console.log(questionBoxElement);
  // reset timer and score
  userScore = 0;
  countdown();
  displayQuestion();
}

// One Line to call one function
quizButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
document.querySelector("#answer-buttons").addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);
```

```html
<div id="quiz-timer"></div>

<header class="start-quiz-intro">
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Coding Quiz</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="center-button">
    <p class="start"> Press Button To Start The Quiz</p>
    <button id="quiz-button">Start</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="hero">
  <div id="question-box" class="hide">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button id="option0" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option1" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option2" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option3" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <h3 id="scores"></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  Thanks for playing my game - Reid
</footer>
```

Comment: So this solved my problem with the questions, but now it doesn't account for correct answers and deducts time from every answer selected

Comment: Ok, fixed the scoring too